# how can I use AWS Lambda Trigger written in Node.js to insert item in Dynamodb?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have one Dynamodb table. I created another one just like it. I created a Lambda trigger on the first table to capture all the new, updated and deleted items in the first table. I invoke a Lambda function to write the items, update the items or delete the items in the second table. While I can see the events in Cloudwatch along with my console statements the "put" or "putItem" never execute and item never gets inserted (or updated or deleted) in the second table. So I need some help.

I've tried a couple of different versions of the following code:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-2'});

var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

    event.Records.forEach((record) => {
        console.log('New MY Stream record: ', JSON.stringify(record, null, 2));
        

        if (record.eventName == 'INSERT') {
           console.log('New MY INSERTING RECORD');
           
    
           ddb.put({
               "TableName": 'my_jobs_holding',
            "Item": {
                    "attributeone" : {"S":record.dynamodb.NewImage.attributeone},
                    "attributetwo" : {"S":record.dynamodb.NewImage.attributetwo},
                    "attributethree" : {"S":record.dynamodb.NewImage.attributethree},
                    "attributefour" : {"S":record.dynamodb.NewImage.attributefour,
                    "attributefive" : {"S":record.dynamodb.NewImage.attributefive},
                  } 
                  }, function(result) {
                      console.log('MY HERE 1' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
    result.on('data', function(chunk) {
        console.log("MY HERE" + chunk);
    });

                  });
           console.log("New MY COMPLETED INSERTION MODULE");
        }
        
        if (record.eventName == 'DELETE') {
           console.log('New MY DELETING RECORD');
           
                   var params = {
            TableName: 'my_jobs_holding',
            Item: {
                    "attributeone" : {"S":record.dynamodb.NewImage.attributeone},
                    "attributetwo" : {"S":record.dynamodb.NewImage.attributetwo},
                    "attributethree" : {"S":record.dynamodb.NewImage.attributethree},
                    "attributefour" : {"S":record.dynamodb.NewImage.attributefour,
                    "attributefive" : {"S":record.dynamodb.NewImage.attributefive},
                  }
        };
           
           ddb.deleteItem(params, function(err, data) {
           if (err) {
              console.log("New MY DELETING Error", err.stack);
           } else {
              console.log("New MY DEL Success", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
           }
           });
           
        }
        
        if (record.eventName == 'MODIFY') {
           console.log('New MY MODIFYING RECORD');
           
            var params = {
            TableName: 'my_jobs_holding',
            Item: {
                    "attributeone" : {"S":record.dynamodb.NewImage.attributeone},
                    "attributetwo" : {"S":record.dynamodb.NewImage.attributetwo},
                    "attributethree" : {"S":record.dynamodb.NewImage.attributethree},
                    "attributefour" : {"S":record.dynamodb.NewImage.attributefour,
                    "attributefive" : {"S":record.dynamodb.NewImage.attributefive},
                  }
        };
        
           ddb.updateItem(params, function(err,data) {
           if (err) {
              console.log("New MY UPDATING Error", err);
           } else {
              console.log("New MY UPDATING Success",data);
           }
           });
        }
    });
    
    callback(null, `New MY Successfully processed  records.`);
};
```

And I have tried the above where the Insert was like the update and delete defining params first and then using putItem with no luck.

I read somewhere that I should try to test it through the AWS Lambda console. I did and it just spins and spins and spins. but if I actually go to the Dynamodb 1 table and insert an item I can see the results pretty quickly in the Cloudwatch table. I have played around with this code several times triggering errors like "putItem is not a valid function" or the time out errors people reported etc. But I have never been able to get an item to insert into the second Dynamodb table. (Therefore I have never tried the delete or the update.) Also I have just used new AWS.DynamoDB() as well. AND I have commented out the callback at the bottom too. NOTHING gets the item inserted into the second Dynamodb table. I've checked the role/permissions too.

What am I missing here?

Any one have any thoughts here? I would DEFINITELY appreciate it.

Comment: Any errors in the CloudWatch log?

Comment: No I get the console statement "New MY INSERTING RECORD" and the record but I never get an error or the data variable printed out. It just appears to stop. I have worked with this over several days too. So it is not a matter of me waiting long enough for it to finish. So the last statement I see for each event is "New MY COMPLETED INSERTION MODULE" but is like the put or putItem never get executed.

Comment: After not getting any responses or knowing what to do I continued to just play around with this. I added the apiversion and endpoint to new AWS.DynamoDB. I then got an error. It is telling me that for two of the attributes ("host" and "filename") that they must be strings. But they are strings. I even have the "S": in front of them. But at least I'm getting an error.

Comment: When using DocumentClient, you do not need to annotate the types.  Instead of specifying `{"S": attributeone}`, try just `attributeone`.

From the DocumentClient docs: "The document client simplifies working with items in Amazon DynamoDB by abstracting away the notion of attribute values. This abstraction annotates native JavaScript types supplied as input parameters, as well as converts annotated response data to native JavaScript types."

Comment: thanks. I switched back to just regular AWS.DynamoDB. But I removed the type casting/indicator anyway and the error went away. The trigger reports "OK" There are no more errors (again) in Cloud watch but the item is still NOT in the second dynamodb table. So I have no idea why this isn't work.

Comment: Again it is as if the code never gets to ddb.putItem . . . because I am printing out data in teh callback and it never prints it. I put a new console statement in there too and it does print that out to Cloudwatch. Very very odd

Comment: I also switched back to new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(); and changed putItem to put . . . says it worked but no item in the second table. And the second table name is definitely . . . my_jobs_holding